# Windows 10 crashing every couple of days

Tags: windows-10, crash

Windows 10 crashing about once every few days. No pattern in time of day.

```
TurnedOnTimesView
Startup Time    Shutdown Time   Last System Event Time  Duration    Shutdown Reason Shutdown Type   Shutdown Process    Shutdown Code   Computer Name   
10/12/2019 12:08:16 PM      10/13/2019 1:24:02 AM   13:15:46        Unexpected Shutdown     0x00000000  RAGNAROS    
10/13/2019 1:51:28 AM       10/13/2019 4:04:39 AM   02:13:11        Unexpected Shutdown     0x00000000  RAGNAROS
```

The Windows Memory Diagnostic tested the computer's memory and detected no errors

[Dxdiag results.](https://pastebin.com/acWjEqQF)

BlueScreenView:

```
101319-17781-01.dmp 10/13/2019 5:47:18 AM   SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED 0x1000007e  ffffffff`c0000005   fffff804`7ea06463   ffff8400`d3edf408   fffff804`84c0e930   hal.dll hal.dll+6efe0   Hardware Abstraction Layer DLL  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Microsoft Corporation   10.0.18362.387 (WinBuild.160101.0800)   x64 ntoskrnl.exe+6463                   C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\101319-17781-01.dmp 20  15  18362   1,043,684   10/13/2019 5:51:30 AM   
101319-17968-01.dmp 10/13/2019 1:48:24 AM   IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL  0x0000000a  fffff807`f93c0700   00000000`00000002   00000000`00000000   fffff804`0880644a                           x64                     C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\101319-17968-01.dmp 20  15  18362   855,204 10/13/2019 1:51:38 AM
```

Many more of these dumps similar to above.

For the IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL, they look like this:

```
Unknown_Module_00000000`00000000        00000000`00000000   00000000`00000000   0x00000000  0x00000000
```

For the SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED... There is tons of information in [this link](https://pastebin.com/0CFqax2G)

Almost every crash looks like one of these two scenarios.

Power troubleshooter wants my computer to go to sleep. I want my computer to never go to sleep, I use it as a media server. Otherwise it finds nothing wrong.

[Windows 10 Reliability History report.](https://pastebin.com/aqqC67A4)

Turned off the Dell Data Vault Data Collector Service. I don't know how to act on anything else in this report.

Dell support doesn't have any new drivers for the sound card that I can see.

What do I do? How can I pin this problem down? If I can find the software or hardware causing this I will remove it, but I just have no idea what to do now.

Updated info: This summer I reinstalled Windows hoping to fix these issues and also after making a significant hardware change (replacing 3 HDDs).

Comment: 1. Use the Dell Driver updater to update all drivers including BIOS, Chipset and then all remaining drivers. Restart and test.   2. Get TDSSKiller (Kaspersky) and check for Root Kit Malware (which can cause these symptoms

Comment: "1. Use the Dell Driver updater to update all drivers including BIOS, Chipset and then all remaining drivers. Restart and test."

All of this is with all the current drivers for BIOS and Chipset. Dell's automated driver update system has nothing to recommend.

" 2. Get TDSSKiller (Kaspersky) and check for Root Kit Malware (which can cause these symptoms"

Will do.

Comment: TDSSKiller found no threats.

Comment: Run another OS from USB flash drive, e.g. Ubuntu. If it runs successfully for a few days, then the issue is likely with the HDD or OS. If the alternative OS crashes, then it's likely another hardware issue, such as overheating (dust), power supply, dust in contacts (a fungal mycellium can force its way into seated connectors) or video card.

Comment: What is the issue with the sound card (above you said no driver)?

Comment: John, the Window 10 Reliability History report has events in it like:

 <Time>2019-10-13T13:09:19.528</Time>
                <Impact>Critical</Impact>
                <Source>Creative High Definition Audio Service</Source>
                <Problem>Stopped working</Problem>
                <State>Report sent</State>